# jQuery Validation not displaying messages

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validation plugin, for my jQuery mobile site. The validation is hitting, but it is not displaying the error messages. Need help in figuring out what is wrong. Here is my code.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#LoginForm").validate();
    });
</script>




<form id="LoginForm" class="validate" action="~/Home/Search" method="get">
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li data-role="list-divider"><div class="center-wrapper">Secure Login</div></li>

     <li data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="FirmKey">FirmKey</label>
        <input type="text" id="FirmKey" name="FirmKey" class="required" />
    </li>

    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="UserName">User Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="UserName" name="UserName" class="required" />
    </li>

    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" class="required" />
    </li>

    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="LOGIN" />
    </li>
</ul>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
label.error {
    float: none; 
    color: red; 
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.4;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 22%;
}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait){
    label.error { margin-left: 0; display: block; }
}
@media screen and (orientation: landscape){
    label.error { display: inline-block; margin-left: 22%; }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like "$(document).ready(function () { $('#submit').click(function(){$("#LoginForm").validate();}); });" ?  Why would anyone require a validation before hitting submit button?

Comment: @Fresheyeball I have added the CSS in my post.

Comment: @Rajeev:Can you show your validate function?

Comment: @sushil I thought validat() was an inbuilt jquery validation plugin function. It is firing for sure, because the control rests in the element and does not go to next screen.

Comment: It's working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/PrfUj/1/) using your code.

Comment: I see that @SheikhHeera. Thanks. I am using Firefox 5.0. And jQuery Validation Plugin 1.8.1. Does that make a case?

Comment: I don't think so, you can check the fiddle link using FF.

Comment: @SheikhHeera its working... now i am confused... :(

Comment: Check your code again and make sure that plugin.js is loaded properly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12978/discussion-between-rajeev-nair-and-sheikh-heera)

Comment: Using jQuery Validate 1.9 & jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 & jQuery 1.7.1 I have pasted your code into a jsFiddle and it seems to work find by me... http://jsfiddle.net/JkqFH/ is there anything missing?

Comment: Getting bunch of warnings in FF console:

Comment: [17:17:40.631] Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:55209/Content/css?v=NL6UN87DHdfjJwhaCoDiep3dzS1QTDFM5Aw-KGYc3a81:35
[17:17:40.922] Expected media feature name but found '-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio'. @ http://localhost:55209/Content/css?v=NL6UN87DHdfjJwhaCoDiep3dzS1QTDFM5Aw-KGYc3a81:35
[17:17:40.926] Unknown property '-moz-background-size'.  Declaration dropped. @

Answer (score 11):

If you happen to be including the jquery.validation.unobtrusive script, it will .validate() your form before you get a chance to. You need to remove the automatically added validation object from you form before you can call .validate() manually for it to function properly... something along the lines of

```
    $("#theForm").removeData("validator")
    $("#theForm").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
```